# After launching app, it takes 30+ seconds before able to access elements through pywinauto

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

I'm testing a custom WPF application using pywinauto.

When connecting with win32, I don't get any dependents, so I'm connecting with `uia`.

After I launch the application, I can immediately connect with pywinauto, but it takes 30s+ before I'm able to access any elements. After the initial delay, interacting and searching for controls is quick.

I call windows() as a way to wait until the application lets me interact with it.

```
main_app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=APP_PATH)
main_app.windows()
```

On investigation, the hanging seems to occur during: "application.py" > "windows" > "findwindows.find_elements(...)" > "element.children(...).

If I open the application, and wait for 1 minute, and then run the script, then it occurs almost immediately. And finding subsequent controls is quick.

I appear to see this same behaviour when using `inspect.exe` to view the hierarchy. If I refresh immediately after opening the application, it takes 30s+ to show anything. But If I wait a minute before refreshing, it updates immediately.

I was wondering if someone else had experienced this before, and what might be the cause/solution.

I am running:
Windows 10, python 3.8.3, pywinauto 0.6.8

Comment: You can use :
app.window(title='xyz').wait('ready', timeout=40)
Waits until the application is loaded and ready ( or timeout)

Comment: Thanks Vidya, but I'm not wanting to have to wait. I should be able to interact with the UI immediately, and I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with the application preventing it from being ready earlier.

Comment: It looks like some Windows KB update is necessary to fix the issue in MS UI Automation API. I don't recall the exact update link. General tricks about "uia" performance were discussed here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/256 (need to collect all recipes into one document in the future).

Comment: Thanks @VasilyRyabov for that link, I had seen that issue previously, but assumed it would be resolved in newer versions of Windows like I'm running. I tried installing that specific KB but get error that it's "not applicable this image".
The more I've investigated, it seems to be an issue with a specific sub-process I'm running that is confusing the system. Doesn't seem necessarily related to pywinauto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging some more, I have resolved the issue, although it's not clear to me what the root cause actually was.

The custom application I'm testing launches a background application as a non-visible console. Testing showed that not running this background application allowed me to conenct immediately. Running the background application by itself would cause the same delay in `inspect.exe` loading.

The application was a dotnet framework application, that in theory was a console only application, but had code supporting a WPF interface (which was not displayed). By removing the WPF aspects of the project, I was able to build the application as a purely console application, and I no longer experienced the earlier delays.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes setting an application as an firewall exceptions helps them boot/open faster.
Granting Firewall exception on Windows 10 for an application:

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Click Windows Firewall or Windows Defender Firewall option.
3. Choose option "Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall" (on left side).
4. Select your application in the list or click on Add Another App to find it and add it to list.

Comment: Thanks Vidya, the application itself launches fast. I can manually interact it with, but once it's loaded, it still takes ~30s before any function calls through pywinauto start taking effect.